How to properly document stringified JSON with Swagger?
After fighting with ChatGPT about this, I suspect that what I am trying to achieve is not possible, but hope is not fully lost just yet.
I have an API endpoint which returns a JSON response containing 2 fields: an id which is an integer, an event_name as a string and an event_data field which is a string containing a JSON. Like this:
{
  "id": 1,
  "event_name": "typeA",
  "event_data": "{\"action\": \"Action1\", \"value\": \"some-string\"}"
}

The catch is that event_name can be one of 3 values: typeA, typeB and typeC and based on that, there's a cascading effect like if it is TypeA then event_data will have an action key which can be Action1 or Action2.
My current approach is to just document the fields:
properties:
  id:
    type: integer
  event_name:
    type: string
    enum: [TypeA, TypeB, TypeC]
  event_data:
    type: string
    format: json

and use the ednpoint description to provide the possible values for `event_data.
What I am trying to achieve is to have the JSON description inside the response schema in a more user-friendly fashion. It would have been great if something like this would have worked but it does not:
properties:
  id:
    type: integer
  event_name:
    type: string
    enum: [TypeA, TypeB, TypeC]
  event_data:
    type: string
    format: json
    oneOf:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/TypeA'
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/TypeB'
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/TypeC'

components:
  schemas:
    TypeA:
      type: object
      properties:
        action:
          type: string
          enum: [Action1, Action2]
        value:
          type: string
   TypeB:
      type: object
      properties:
        ...
   TypeC:
      type: object
      properties:
        ...

Is there a way to do that?

when you say it doesn't work, what is that exactly?  Validation? which tool are you using?   Your use of oneOf as a sibling to type: string produces an illogical schema. You can't define a schema with type: string and then $ref an object schema.  In your case, event_data is a string and the only way to validate anything inside the json string is to use pattern, which can be super hairy.

In OpenAPI 3.1, JSON-formatted strings can be defined using the contentMediaType and contentSchema keywords. However, actual tooling support for these keywords (e.g. for validation / serialization / deserialization purposes) is probably non-existent.
  event_data:
    type: string

    contentMediaType: application/json
    contentSchema:
      type: object
      required: [action, value]
      properties:
        action:
          type: string
          example: Action1
        value:
          type: string
          example: some-string
      additionalProperties: false


The catch is that event_name can be one of 3 values: typeA, typeB and typeC and based on that, there's a cascading effect like if it is TypeA then event_data will have an action key which can be Action1 or Action2.

I would suggest documenting these constraints in the description of the schema or endpoint.
While it's technically possible to use oneOf/anyOf/discriminator/etc. to vary one property's contentSchema based on another property's value, it makes little sense to bother with this given the lack of tooling support.
